# Javascript to get .pdf file from partial match

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, regex

Complete and utter javascript newbie here with a problem fetching .pdf files from a web server based on a partial match.  I have made a program that outputs data to a webserver, and one of the components is a folder of .pdf files.  I want to be able to click on a link that will pull up the corresponding .pdf file based on a value in the data table that's generated (I'm using slickgrid for this).  Each of the .pdf files contains the value that's in the data table and serves as good query to the .pdf folder, and I've been successful at getting the .pdfs I want with the following code:

```
var value = grid.getData().getItem(row)['data'];
var locpath = window.location.pathname.substring(0,window.location.pathname.lastIndexOf('/'));
var plotsFolder = window.location.protocol + "//" + window.location.host + locpath + "/CovPlots/";
var href = plotsFolder + value + ".pdf";
return "<a href='" + href + "'>" + value + "</a>";
```

The catch here is that sometimes the .pdf file that's generated is a concatenation of two or more (I've seen up to 4 so far) of the 'data' strings, separated by '_' as a delimiter for reasons not worth getting into.  So, if the .pdf file is 'somestring.pdf', I can get it without problem.  However, if the .pdf file is 'somestring_anotherstring.pdf', I can't figure out how to get that .pdf file if I have either 'somestring' or 'anotherstring' as the value of 'data'.

I've tried a ton of different things to get some kind of lookup that I can use to pull down the correct file based on a partial match.  The latest attempt is with the FilenameFilter object in javascript, but without any knowledge of javascript, I'm having a hard time to get it working.  I tried to create a new function that I could call as a lookup for the .pdf URL:

```
function lookup() {
    File directory = new File(plotsFolder);
    String[] myFiles = directory.list(new FilenameFilter() {
        public boolean accept(File directory, String fileName) {
        return fileName.match(value);
        }
    });
}
```

That only seems to thrown an error.  Can anyone point me in the right direction to be able to download the correct .pdf file based on a partial match?  I also tried to see if there was a jquery way to do it, but couldn't seem to find something that works.  Thanks in advance!

Comment: That `lookup` function is a weird amalgamation between Java and JavaScript, so if you were curious, that's why it's not working: those languages are not interchangeable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without support from the server, JavaScript cannot find a file from a partial filename. What you can do, however, is have a little script on the server that does the partial-filename-matching for JavaScript, and then JavaScript can ask the server to do the match, and then when it gets the match back, it can use that filename.

If you don't mind loading a whole index of all the PDFs at once, you could use this little Python script to generate an index in a nice, JavaScript-friendly JSON format:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# Create an index of a bunch of PDF files.
# Usage: python make_index.py directory_with_pdf_files

import os
import sys
import json


def index(directory):
    index = {}

    for filename in os.listdir(directory):
        base, ext = os.path.splitext(filename)
        if ext.lower() != '.pdf':
            continue
        for keyword in base.split('_'):
            index[keyword] = filename

    with open(os.path.join(directory, 'index.json'), 'w') as f:
        f.write(json.dumps(index))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    index(sys.argv[1])
```

Then you can just load `index.json` with jQuery or what-have-you. When you need to find a particular PDF's filename, you can do something like this (assuming the object loaded from `index.json` is in the `indexOfPDFs` variable):

```
var href = plotsFolder + indexOfPDFs[value];
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help!  Creating a JSON index is a good idea.  However, I'm struggling to get a Jquery call to the script in order to generate the file (the script is working alone, though). This is all completely new to me and I'll seem to be able to code is complete gibberish.  I can't seem to figure out how to post my attempts in this field either.

Comment: @user2059832: I was thinking not that the jQuery would trigger a JSON index being created, but that you would run that script whenever some new PDFs were added to the directory.

Comment: @user2059832: You could also convert that Python script to, say, PHP, which would generate the JSON index on the fly. (It's also possible to make the Python script do it on the fly, but if you have PHP already configured (which is likely), it would be less work to just port it.)

Comment: OK, that makes sense.  I integrated the python script into the pipeline that generates the data, and it did make the .json file as expected.  However, I get an error in the `var href = plotsFolder + indexOfPDFs[value][0];` line saying `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined`.  I'm loading up the variable with `var indexOfPDFs = locpath + "pdf_index.json";'  Is this the wrong way to access the .json file?

Comment: @user2059832: Yeah; you're setting `indexOfPDFs` to a string, but what you really should be doing is *loading* the JSON file at that location using [`jQuery.getJSON`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON) or something.

Comment: Thank you again for all of your help.  I see where I was going wrong.  Using jquery to load up the JSON file seems to be working.  I'm still having a bit of a time trying to parse the JSON array (for some reason I'm only getting a part of the value (each letter of the value indexed by the key - so indexOfPDFs[value][0] returns the first letter of the value and indexOfPDFs[value][1] returns the second), but I think it's a matter of some more reading on how to handle arrays in javascript.  I never thought this would be so difficult to do, and I greatly appreciate all of your help and effort!

Comment: @user2059832: Sorry, that's my fault. Remove the `[0]`. I was unsure of whether the index should list all of the PDF files with that substring or just one of them. I was kind of torn between which to do, and I guess a bit of both got into my answer.